# Autocomplete change Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have to make 2 fields with autocomplete text:

```
<input type="text" id="province" />
<input type="text" id="city" />
```

Javascript

```
$("#province").autocomplete({
source:'/province.php',
minLength: 3,
select: function(event, ui) {
$("#province").val(ui.item.id);
}
});
```

When changing of provinces you have to load the cities of #city.
How can you do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $("#province").autocomplete({
 source:'/province.php',
 minLength: 3,
 select: function(event, ui) 
 {
   $("#province").val(ui.item.id);
   $("#city").autocomplete({source:'/city.php'}); //Reload city data
 }
});
```

Comment: ok how can I pass the parameter of the province so as to make a query like this in city.php:

SELECT * FROM city WHERE id_province = $ _REQUEST['terms']

Comment: I've never worked in php, but I think you could pass parameters using the "source" link, as if it were a "GET" type call, like this: `source:'/city.php?param=' + ui.item.id `